# Appending content into template tag

Tags: javascript, html5-template

I am trying to append content into template tag. I am using

```
getcontent("clients.json").then(function(x){
   obj = JSON.parse(x);
}).then(function(x){

   var x = createFullList(obj,docFragment);
   filtered = obj;
   return x;
}).then(function(x){
   template   .appendChild(x);
   var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
   alert(clone.children.length);
   aside.appendChild(clone)
});
```

getcontent is ajax call that returns response , the response is parsed and stored as object in obj variable ,

createFullList creates divs for every element in ajax response and append it into fragment , fragment is then appended into div that is also returned ,

```
function createFullList( obj , fragment ){
   var aside       = document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0];
   for( x in obj ){
      createInfoElement( fragment , obj[x].general , obj[x].job , x);
   }
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   div.appendChild(fragment);
   deleteKid( aside , 1 );
   return div;
}
```

what troubles me is appending into template , it does nothin , when i try to copy its content , it says it has 0 children , altought if i print children of div it prints correct number.

Why isnt content appended into template? Is this a right way or is there any specific way how to correctly append content into template?

Answer (score 1):

You should append the fragment in `template.content` instead of `template`:

```
template.content.appendChild( x )
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use just one `then()`, like so:

```
var obj;
getcontent("clients.json").then(function(x){
   obj = JSON.parse(x);
}).then(function(){
  var x = createFullList(obj, docFragment);
  filtered = obj;

  template.appendChild(x);
  var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
  alert(clone.children.length);
  aside.appendChild(clone)

  return(x);
});
```

I believe you're trying to reference a variable that is not available in the scope that `template.appendChild()` is referring it to.

Comment: this is not the case , when i try to alert(x.children.length) it outputs the right amount of children. Also just to be sure i tried it and behavior remains same.